# Resuming persisted WorkFlow (WorkFlow Foundation 4.5)

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

Im trying to resume a persisted work flow. The Workflow is running local on a client machine and is attached to a WindowsForms Application

The bookmark is created in a extension activity like here:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Will be executed if the bookmark gets executed.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        ScanBarcodeExtension requestToScanBarcode = context.GetExtension<ScanBarcodeExtension>();
        requestToScanBarcode.GetScanResult(UserMessage.Get(context), BookmarkName.Get(context), ExpectedScanActivity.Get(context));
        context.CreateBookmark(BookmarkName.Get(context),  new BookmarkCallback(scanBarcodeCallback));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scans the magazine barcode callback.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <param name="bookmark">The bookmark.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    private void scanBarcodeCallback(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object value)
    {
        WorkflowArgumentContainer container = context.GetValue(this.ArgumentContainer);
        switch ((ScanActivity)ExpectedScanActivity.Get(context))
        {
            case ScanActivity.FAUF:
                container.FaufId = (value as string);
                break;
            case ScanActivity.Magazine:
                container.CurrentMagazine.ID = (value as string);
                break;
            case ScanActivity.AluPack:
                container.PrintAluPackLabelProcessResult.ScannedLabelContent = (value as string);
                break;
            case ScanActivity.Box:
                container.PrintBoxLabelProcessResult.ScannedLabelContent = (value as string);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        Result.Set(context, container);
    }
```

When i call

```
wfApp.ResumeBookmark(bookmarkName, value);
```

from a running application, everything works fine.

Now i close the application and doing the following things:

- Check in the sql table for an existing id
- getting the ID
- configuring the workflow
- trying to resume the bookmark

An this looks like this:

```
   logger.Info("Persisted workflow found. Loading workflow states...");
        WorkflowApplicationInstance instance = WorkflowApplication.GetInstance(this.workflowInstanceId, sqlStore);
        WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new ConditioningWF(), instance.DefinitionIdentity);

        logger.Info("Configuring persisted workflow...");
        this.configureWorkflowApplication(wfApp);

        wfApp.Load(instance);
        logger.Info("Getting blocking bookmarks from persisted workflow...");
        string bookmark = this.getBlockingBookmarksFromPersistedWorkFlow(wfApp.Id);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bookmark))
            throw new MissingArgumentExceptions(string.Format("Kein Bookmark für den persistierten WorkFlow mit der ID '{0}' gefunden!", wfApp.Id));

        logger.Info("Running persisted workflow...");
        wfApp.Run();

        logger.InfoFormat("Resuming bookmark '{0}'...", bookmark);
        wfApp.ResumeBookmark("ScanMagazine", string.Empty);
```

Implementation of configureWorkFlowApplication looks like this:

```
 private void configureWorkflowApplication(WorkflowApplication wfApp)
    {
        // Configure the persistence store.
        wfApp.InstanceStore = sqlStore;

        // Instance the extensions...
        MESWebserviceExtension mesDataAccessExtension = new MESWebserviceExtension();
        ExceptionNotificationExtension exceptionNotifiyExtension = new ExceptionNotificationExtension();
        ScanBarcodeExtension scanBarcodeExtension = new ScanBarcodeExtension();
        NotifyFaufRegisteredExtension notifyFaufRegisteredExtension = new NotifyFaufRegisteredExtension();
        FuseAluPackExtension fuseAluPackExtension = new FuseAluPackExtension();

        exceptionNotifiyExtension.OnNotifiyException += exceptionNotifiyExtension_OnNotifiyException;
        scanBarcodeExtension.OnGetFaufScan += scanBarcodeExtension_OnGetFaufScan;
        notifyFaufRegisteredExtension.OnFaufRegistered += notifyFaufRegisteredExtension_OnFaufRegistered;
        scanBarcodeExtension.OnGetMagazinScan += scanBarcodeExtension_OnGetMagazinScan;
        fuseAluPackExtension.OnGetFuseResult += fuseAluPackExtension_OnGetFuseResult;


        //...add extensions
        wfApp.Extensions.Add(exceptionNotifiyExtension);
        wfApp.Extensions.Add(mesDataAccessExtension);

        wfApp.Extensions.Add(notifyFaufRegisteredExtension);
        wfApp.Extensions.Add(scanBarcodeExtension);
        wfApp.Extensions.Add(fuseAluPackExtension);

        #region WF States changed
        wfApp.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CompletionState == ActivityInstanceState.Faulted)
            {
                logger.Error(String.Format("...Workflow '{0}' terminated: {1}", e.InstanceId, e.TerminationException.Message), e.TerminationException);

                if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                {
                    MboxStatus(string.Format("Workflow Terminated. Exception: {0}\r\n{1}",
                        e.TerminationException.GetType().FullName,
                        e.TerminationException.Message));
                }
            }
            else if (e.CompletionState == ActivityInstanceState.Canceled)
            {

                logger.WarnFormat("...Workflow '{0}' canceled...", e.InstanceId);

                if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                {
                    MboxStatus("Workflow Canceled.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                logger.WarnFormat("...Workflow '{0}' completed...", e.InstanceId);

                if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                {
                    MboxStatus("Fertig");
                }
            }
        };

        wfApp.Aborted = delegate(WorkflowApplicationAbortedEventArgs e)
        {
            logger.Error(String.Format("...Workflow '{0}' aborted  '{0}' : {1}",
                    e.InstanceId, e.Reason.Message), e.Reason);


            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                MboxStatus(string.Format("Workflow Aborted. Exception: {0}\r\n{1}",
                        e.Reason.GetType().FullName,
                        e.Reason.Message));
            }
        };

        wfApp.OnUnhandledException = delegate(WorkflowApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            logger.Error(String.Format("...UnhandledException occured in Workflow '{0}' : {1}",
                                    e.InstanceId, e.UnhandledException.Message), e.UnhandledException);


            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                MboxStatus(string.Format("Unhandled Exception: {0}\r\n{1}",
                        e.UnhandledException.GetType().FullName,
                        e.UnhandledException.Message));
            }
            return UnhandledExceptionAction.Terminate;
        };

        wfApp.PersistableIdle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
        {
            logger.InfoFormat("...Workflow '{0}' unloaded...", e.InstanceId);

            return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
        };

        // Workflow lifecycle events omitted except idle.
        AutoResetEvent idleEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        wfApp.Idle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
        {
            idleEvent.Set();
        };
        #endregion

        logger.Info("...configuring WorkflowApplication finished...");
    }
```

**The Problem**
After calling

```
   wfApp.ResumeBookmark("ScanMagazine", string.Empty);
```

Nothing happens.. truly nothing.
I think the program should jump to the scanBarcodeCallback or am i doing something wrong? For the moment it is really frustrating cuz i cant handle this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Found in msdn forum the following: Workflow Engine doesn't need this data to resume Workflow Instance. In order to resume engine loads workflow instance into memory and then tries to resume bookmark. So getting the last bookmark is unnecessary?! But how do i resume the workflow then? Confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you are doing first Run then Resume:

`wfApp.Run();`

`wfApp.ResumeBookmark("ScanMagazine", string.Empty);`

For resuming bookmarks only ResumeBookmark is needed. Just remove `wfApp.Run();` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks very very mutch! Was too easy... Never trust the MSDN Forums ;x